# XSS errors with recent update

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, noscript

I have been using Tor for about a year now and been happy with the project, at least until the last update 5.5.4, which is behaving oddly. :((

One site I used to visit often was mail.com, where I access my mail. Since the last update, however, I cannot access the site at all--I get this error message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /mail.com/current/html/error.html was not found on this server.

Noscript now claims to be filtering a "potential cross-site scripting (XSS)" from the site it never had problems with before.

Now I cannot access my mail. What can I do, other than not use Tor?

Comment: It could be that the newer version of Tor has a newer version of NoScript, and the newer NoScript has been updated to find newer problems which it couldn't detect before, including on that site. If that's the case, then you'll have to decide if you trust mail.com enough to whitelist (i.e. ignore) it in NoScript.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That may be the case, but it seems odd that NoScript found nothing in previous updates to worry about  . . .